# Not able to parse to design view in window builder

Tags: java, windowbuilder

I am using window builder to create Java GUI, but today unfortunately I faced one problem when I was moving from coding view to design view. And I am getting bellow error

> Eclipse is running under 0, but this Java project has a 10 Java compliance level, so Window Builder will not be able to load classes from this project. Use a lower level of Java for the project, or run Eclipse using a newer Java version.

So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/50191328/2849346 and it's answer/explanation of the current situation.

Answer (score 0):

I just rolled back to java 9 and gave a try .it worked.

Comment: That is clearly only a short term solution, as Java 9 is already EOL.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, solved by updating by Eclipse.
Go to: Help--Check for Updates, then update all