# I wanted to use eclipse gui but i am getting wrong java versions

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

I want to use swing methods like **Jframe,Jbutton** etc.. But i am getting the code part but not the design part.

The first image shows the console output:

[image]

It show unable to import swing library:

[image]

Comment: You already try to configure JRE in preferences, right?

Comment: @rkosegi i have jre 10.0.2 and jdk 10.0.2. they work perfectly when i use java for programming

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50267304/2849346 - It is a known problem, yet unsolved. :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with 'Incompatible Java Versions running 0' in Eclipse Window Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50191328/how-to-deal-with-incompatible-java-versions-running-0-in-eclipse-window-builde)