# I want to use different JDK version on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

On the Design tab of the WindowBuilder,
it says the following message: 
Eclipse is running under 0,
but this Java project has a 10 Java compliance level,
so WindowBuilder will not be able to load classes from this project.
Use a lower level of Java for the project,
or run Eclipse using a newer Java version.

I'm running Eclipse Jee Photon with JDK 10 on Window OS.
I want to use different JDK version on eclipse

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1093118/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50191328/how-to-deal-with-incompatible-java-versions-running-0-in-eclipse-window-builde